# Understanding how Custom UIViews are initialized from IB

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, interface-builder

I made a custom UIView object `customView`

The main initializer i used during prototyping was:

```
public init(textString: String, frame: CGRect) {
```

Once I want to add this little guy to the IB I'm not sure how to get it working.  I understand that once I add the function to the Interface builder it calls:

```
required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

I'm at a loss at this point how to get my custom `textString` passed into the initializer

Is there a process to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Custom UIView has two init methods which are :

```
initWithFrame:frame
initWithCoder:aDecoder
```

You do not use this two methods to pass data like your textString. Instead textString should be a property of your view. This property will be initialized via a View Controller that owns your custom view.

```
@interface CustomView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *textString;

@end
```

Then you set the textString property's value in the View Controller, for instance in its viewDidLoad method.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomView *myCustomView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
    self.myCustomView.textString = @"There's my textString";
}

@end
```

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 1):

Make your custom view @IBDesignable, and the text property @IBInspectable, then you can set the text from inside the storyboard/xib file.